# Can't find variable for button inside if/else

Tags: c#, if-statement, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to have a different margin for iOS and Android so I tried to make if/else but the MyButton cannot be found when then button is inside the if/else like this:

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            var MyButton = new Button
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(0, -15, 0, 0)                    
            };

        }
        else
        {
            var MyButton = new Button
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(-10, -15, 0, 0)                   
            };

        }           

        var MyStackLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { MyButton }               
        };
```

The name MyButton does not exist in the current context.
Is there a work around or a different method for this?

Comment: Try creating `MyButton` before the `if`

Comment: Still the same error: Does not exist in the context. @Henkan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code as below:

```
    Button MyNewButton;
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
    {
        MyNewButton= new Button
        {
            Margin = new Thickness(0, -15, 0, 0)                    
        };

    }
    else
    {
        MyNewButton= new Button
        {
            Margin = new Thickness(-10, -15, 0, 0)                   
        };

    }           

    var MyStackLayout = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = { MyNewButton}               
    };
```

When you define a variable in if body, it cannot be access in out of if body.
And if you declare variable with the same name (Mybutton), change this button name.

Comment: Gives me this error: A local or parameter named 'MyButton' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter @Saeed Bolhasani

Comment: @KalleP Change MyButton name.

Comment: Make the edit and I'll mark it complete. @Saeed Bolhasani

Comment: You didnt have to change the name. You forgot to remove the variables.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned multiple times, the problem is that `MyButton` is living in a wrong scope. What is a scope?

> The scope of a variable determines its visibility to the rest of a
>   program. In the examples throughout the C# Fundamentals tutorial,
>   variables have been defined within methods. When created in this way,
>   the scope of the variable is the entire method after the declaration.
>   This means that the variable is available to use within the method but
>   when control passes to another method the variable is unavailable.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx).